# Zammad Community sporadic Error 405 Not Allowed behind Synology nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: nginx, apache2.4, synology, ubuntu-20.04, zammad

This morning I get *sometimes irregularly* the **405 Not Allowed** error message on my Zammad Community App !

== **Info**

- Ubuntu 20.04LTS
- Apache/2.4.41
- Zammad Community 3.4.x
- ElasticSearch 7.8.1 Deb
- Synology DSM 6.2.3.25426

== **Error details**

Error 405 on modal with the tag `<center>nginx</center>` in response.

[image: Error 405 Not Allowed Zammad Community]

It is, weird because I am using Apache and not nginx.

== **Apache conf**

```
Listen 4000

<VirtualHost *:4000>

    ServerName        int-srv-1

    HostnameLookups   Off
    UseCanonicalName  Off
    ServerSignature   Off

    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy int-srv-1:3000>
        Require local
    </Proxy>
    
    ProxyPass /assets !
    ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
    ProxyPass /robots.txt !
    ProxyPass /ws ws://127.0.0.1:6042/
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

    DocumentRoot "/opt/zammad/public"

    <Directory "/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/opt/zammad/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

But we use a "built-in" Reverse Proxy running our Synology NAS called "App Portal" to access this awesome helpdesk from outside the network (with fixed IP) available at https://hello.ourdomain.ext as the following :

== **Synology NAS conf**

[image: Synology NAS Reverse Proxy config for Zammad Community]

[image: Synology NAS Reverse Proxy config for Zammad Community - General]

[image: Synology NAS Reverse Proxy config for Zammad Community - Advanced Settings]

So, I think **Synology is answering this Error message** because it uses nginx (I believe).

**But Why?**

Does HSTS or HTTP/2 could help ?

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, a workaround seems to work.

The increase of timeout from 60 to 120sec on the advanced proxy options (Reverse Proxy Rules > Advanced Settings) seems to be paying off.

[image: Reverse Proxy Rules Advanced Settings timeout increased]